# android:fontFamily is only working with AppCompatTextView

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-fonts

I was moving my project drop Calligraphy and use the native android android support for fonts. However, I can only make it work if I use AppCompat elements instead of the default ones (TextView, Button, etc..). I wanted to know if this is expected and if not, how could I solve it?

Comment: app theme should extends from AppCompat e.g. <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">,   
and activity should extends from AppCompatActivity

Comment: @Eugene I am doing those two things

Comment: What is your minimum Android API level and what version of the Support library are you using? When using default components, Android will default to the `AppCompat` versions when appropriate, so on newer versions of Android it won't necessarily use the `AppCompat` version. It's only if the specific methods are not supported in the default components, that it will use the `AppCompat` versions of the components.
On a side-note: you should only have to use the `AppCompat` versions of the components if you're writing custom components.

Comment: My minimum API level is 21 and I am using androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0; I also expected that behavior but something really weird is happening for me @Darwind

Answer (score 2):

So I figured it out:

The problem was that in on of the legacy `BaseActivity#onCreate` we were calling `setContentView` before the call to `super.onCreate()`. By doing this it will somehow disable the font from being correctly rendered.